# How does Word find matching word forms in Advanced Search?

Tags: c#, algorithm, search, ms-word, stemming

I have a word document that has occurrences of both "perform" and "performance". When I use the advanced find tool in the Word UI (goal to eventually translate this to the Find.Execute command for C# programmatic searching), I get difference results when i have the Match All Word Forms option checked.

When I search for "perform", I get both the occurrences for "perform" and "performance".
 
When I search for "performance", I only get hits for "performance", even though "perform" should still register as a word form for "performance".

Does anyone know how Word uses its search algorithm or how I could make sure searching for "performance" shows both the results for "perform" and "performance"?

Edit (7/11/12 16:34)-
I ran a couple of test combinations to see if I could find a pattern for myself, and well... it wasnt all that promising (Capitalization matters !?!).
The document these results were obtained from was a simple word document with both upper and lowercase capitalization of each word form. Each search found both the upper and lowercase versions of the word.
[image: Here are the results of a few searches and their apparent conclusions] 
(Do a 'RightClick->Open Image In New Tab' to see the full-size image detail)
If anyone can link to documentation clarifying this for me it would be greatly appreciated!

Edit (7/12/12 9:49)-
Even more sadness: I tried switching from the interface inside Word to the Find.Execute command in C# and the matchSoundsLike parameter does not function in the same way that the UI Advanced Find functions :( It seems that the programmatic matchSoundsLike flag only finds sounds-like forms that match case, even though I have matchCase explicitly set to false.

Comment: I misread your question, scratching my comment.  Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be an adaptation of [Query Expansion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_expansion), a rather important area in Information Retrieval.

I would advise against building a query expansion engine yourself as that's more of a project for a Masters (or possibly a PhD) thesis than a smaller feature of a larger project. However, if you still wish to implement this feature yourself I suggest you start with a [Google Scholar search for "query expansion"](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=query+expansion&btnG=&hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&as_vis=1) and read up on some of the modern techniques.

As far as pre-existing libraries, most packages focus on web searches and databases so I'm having a hard time finding anything for searching text files. [Google Query Expansion](https://developers.google.com/search-appliance/documentation/68/help_gsa/serve_query_expansion) doesn't explicitly say that it's an extension for Google APIs, but that's the impression that I get. Microsoft SQL Server seems to [have this functionality built-in](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142491.aspx). There's an [Apache Lucene module](http://lucene-qe.sourceforge.net/) which also implements this. MySQL also has [an implementation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-query-expansion.html).

If you wish to use a pre-existing package it seems you will at the very least need to modify your program's structure such that the text is stored in a database. This would change your problem from a text search problem into a corpus search problem, which are heavily studied and will have more documentation and tools by outside sources. That said, without knowing your data I don't know if this is a worth-while solution nor what structure you should choose.

Best of luck. I am sorry I was unable to directly answer your question but I hope I gave you some good sources of information.

Comment: Thanks for the links! I can keep query expansion in mind, but converting my data over to a database doesn't seem to be beneficial since the word form matching functionality is such a small feature of the overall program.

Comment: @ChrisW. That was kind of what I figured. That's why I said  that implementing your own system might not be a great idea. Searching for partial matches, such as `PERFORMance` or ignoring capitalizations are trivial (regex and some `string.toLower()` method, respectively. I don't know C# so I don't know what the method is called), but finding the stem of a query term (i.e. "perform" from "performance") as well as finding synonyms and their variations would be annoying to program and probably more trouble than it's worth. Sorry.